# Copy SharePoint 2010 Pages to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, page-layout

We have a SharePoint 2010 external website that has a few years of archived press releases.  We are going to migrate to SharePoint 2013.

I tried copying some pages from the SP2010 website to the SP2013 website.  The pages look like they copied, but when I click on a page in the Pages library, it says "Sorry, something went wrong.  File not found."

I am assuming it has something to do with the page layout that the page is using in SP2010 which we do not have in 2013.  Is there a way to change the page layout without opening the page?

I am not wanting to recreate 550 pages of archived press releases.  Looking for an easier method to copy these pages over to the 2013 site.

***UPDATE***
Turns out I can use Sharegate Migration to copy the 2010 pages and select a template (pick my 2013 page layout) from the list of choices.  Worked!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628538/sharepoint-2013-change-existing-publishing-page-page-layout-in-csom similar thread in SO

Answer (score 1):

The code base between SP2013 and SP2010 is very different. You have to migrate the content database from your 2010 environment to a 2013 environment. Then you need to mupgrade the UI version of the site collection your pages library lives in. When that's done, you can copy the pages to the destination. It's a lot of work, but it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct, the page layouts used by the pages were not available in target SharePoint 2013. First, consider to migrate the page layouts and then migrate your pages.